# Major time differences according to position of '@' in query string - why?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I'm running an SQL query on a large table populated by millions of records.
The WHERE conditions are a series of LIKEs, comparing the input against a few textual fields.

Below are the time the query takes to run for various inputs (an average of 3-5 runs each).

```
* 'aaaa' : ~3.1 seconds
* 'aaa@' : ~2 seconds
* 'aa@a' : ~9.7 seconds
* 'a@aa' : ~9.7 seconds
* 'aa@a' : ~9.8 seconds
```

All queries returned a similar number of results (12-13).
I've checked this with other letters (non-repeating etc) instead of the 'a's, and the results were more or less the same.

What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: What's the rest of the query look like, and what indexes do you have on the relevant fields? `@` is not metacharcter within strings, so most likely it's something else.

Comment: It's more likely to be related to the data against which those literals are compared; the `LIKE` operator is almost certainly implemented using a 'lazy' pattern insofar as it returns false on encountering the *first* non-matching character (and therefore it avoids scanning the remainder of the string) - therefore strings which match on more of the early characters will take longer to compare.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned on comments above, it's more likely to be related to the distribution of this data in the table. Try creating an index on the table. I can't point you in the right index and how but if you post your schema etc I would be glad to help you out.

Second, Likes are never good, couldn't you improve it on the application code and run equals instead?